# Proving the expectation of a variable in a stochastic process

Tags: self-study, expected-value, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

### Problem

Information packets arrive at a server with a poisson process having rate $\lambda = 2$ per hour.

The server processing time for a packet follows the distribution : $f(x) = 1, 0\leq x\leq1$

The status of the server is *busy* if it is processing a packet, otherwise it is *waiting*. If a packet arrives while the server is *busy*, **that packet is lost**.

Let $t_B$ denote the length of one busy period, $t_I$ denote the length of one idle period. Find the distrubutions of $t_B$ & $t_I$.

Let $N$ denote the total number of lost packets, $T_B$ denote the total *busy* time of the server up until time $T=10$ hours.

Show that :
$$
\begin{align}
 E[N] = \lambda E[T_B]
\end{align}
$$

### My attempt :

$t_B$ is simply the time taken for the server to process a packet, so its distribution is also $f(x) = 1, 0 \leq x \leq 1$

$t_I$ is the inter-arrival time between two packets which follows an $Exp(\lambda = 2)$ distribution, using the relation between poisson & exponential rv's.

In trying to prove the equation, this is what I have so far :

N = total no. of lost packets = no. of packets arriving during $T_B$(while the server is *busy*)

$$
\begin{align}
E[N] &= E[\textrm{No. of arrivals during }T_B] \\
 &=E[\textrm{No. of arrivals per unit time}]\cdot E[T_B] \\
&=\lambda E[T_B]~\textrm{(Shown)}
\end{align}
$$

Am I going about this the right way? If so is there a proper way to express this in math notation? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the packets arrive as a Poisson process, with a given $T_{B}$, the number of missing packets $N$ also follows a Poisson distribution,
$$
p(N \vert T_B) = {\rm Poisson}(\lambda T_B)(N).
$$
The expected value of $N$, ${\rm E}[N]$ is then given by
$$
\begin{aligned}
{\rm E}[N] &= \sum_{N=0}^{\infty} \ N p(N)\\
&= \sum_{N=0}^{\infty} N \int_0^\infty dT_B \  p(N, T_B)\\
&= \sum_{N=0}^{\infty} N \int_0^\infty dT_B \ p(N \vert T_B) p(T_B)\\
&= \int_0^\infty dT_B \ p(T_B) \sum_{N=0}^{\infty} N p(N \vert T_B)\\
&= \int_0^\infty dT_B \ p(T_B) {\rm E}[N \vert T_B]\\
&= \int_0^\infty dT_B \ p(T_B) \lambda T_B\\
&= \lambda \int_0^\infty dT_B \ T_B p(T_B)\\
&= \lambda {\rm E}[T_B].
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think I understand. 

Could I check why $E(N|T_B) = \lambda T_B$?

Since $p(N|T_B) = Poisson(\lambda T_B)(N)$ wouldn't $E(N|T_B) = \lambda T_B N$? Have I misunderstood something?

Comment: The notion of $E(N\vert T_B)$ is the expected value of $N$ given $T_B$. Because the distribution $N\vert T_B \sim {\rm Poisson}(\lambda T_B)$, the expected value is simply $\lambda T_B$ as it is the property of a Poisson distribution.

Comment: I understand. Thank you so much! :)